# Cummulative Updates

Tags: 2007

Can somebody let me know the exact idea behind cummulative update. Microsoft has released lot of cummulative updates in recent years . In our machine we have updated only upto Dec 2008.

Can i directly update the latest cummulative update will that be having all the previous versions in it ?

Answer (score 1):

Cumulative updates (CU) are hotfixes and are compared to Service Packs (SP) not as thorougly tested. They should only be installed if you experience any of the issues resolved in the CU. You only need to install the latest CU to get earlier CU's.

All CU's are added to the next coming SP.

Note that SharePoint 2007 and SharePoint 2010 treats CU's differently. For SharePoint 2007 there is one WSS 3 CU and one MOSS 2007 CU. While in SharePoint 2010 a CU is created for the different parts of SharePoint such as Core, Service Applications etc.

More details can also be found here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953878

Comment: For a MOSS 2007 environment, Should we install the WSS Updates also, or MOSS is enough?

Comment: The WSS updates must be installed before the MOSS ones.

Comment: Rob is right on the spot, the order of installation is really important in 2007! Good thing is that this is changed in 2010!